# Problema para mostrar monto en highcharts

Tags: javascript

un arreglo de números en javascript.

y esto siempre cero por que?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aquí Código:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 
  var arrayMonto = [];
  
 arrayMonto.push({"name":"200000"},{"name":"35000"});     

  window.console && console.log("arrayMonto ", arrayMonto);
  
 ChartMensual(arrayMonto);

});

function ChartMensual(arrayMonto)
{
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'column'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Monto'
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Enero','Febrero']
    },
    yAxis: {
        min: 0,
        title: {
            text: 'Total'
        },
        stackLabels: {
            enabled: true,
            style: {
                fontWeight: 'bold',
                color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.textColor) || 'gray'
            }
        }
    },
    legend: {
        align: 'right',
        x: -30,
        verticalAlign: 'top',
        y: 25,
        floating: true,
        backgroundColor: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.background2) || 'white',
        borderColor: '#CCC',
        borderWidth: 1,
        shadow: false
    },
    tooltip: {
        headerFormat: '<b>{point.x}</b><br/>',
        pointFormat: '{series.name}: {point.y}<br/>Total: {point.stackTotal}'
    },
    plotOptions: {
        column: {
            stacking: 'normal',
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.dataLabelsColor) || 'white'
            }
        }
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Jane',
        data: arrayMonto
    }]
});

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cada valor del series debe de ser un array con el valor y estas enviando un objeto:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 
  var arrayMonto = [];
  
   arrayMonto.push([200000]);
   arrayMonto.push([300000]);

 ChartMensual(arrayMonto);

});

function ChartMensual(arrayMonto)
{
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'column'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Monto'
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Enero','Febrero']
    },
    yAxis: {
        min: 0,
        title: {
            text: 'Total'
        },
        stackLabels: {
            enabled: true,
            style: {
                fontWeight: 'bold',
                color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.textColor) || 'gray'
            }
        }
    },
    legend: {
        align: 'right',
        x: -30,
        verticalAlign: 'top',
        y: 25,
        floating: true,
        backgroundColor: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.background2) || 'white',
        borderColor: '#CCC',
        borderWidth: 1,
        shadow: false
    },
    tooltip: {
        headerFormat: '<b>{point.x}</b><br/>',
        pointFormat: '{series.name}: {point.y}<br/>Total: {point.stackTotal}'
    },
    plotOptions: {
        column: {
            stacking: 'normal',
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.dataLabelsColor) || 'white'
            }
        }
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Jane',
        data: arrayMonto
    }]
});

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```